# Form submit redirect to new url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a form with a single input box. When the user inputs the data and presses enter - i need the page to be redirected to currentpage.com/userinput/ where currentpage.com is the page we are on and userinput is the data that was typed into the text box.

I know how to achieve this with _GET or _POST but using them is not an option. Can some one please offer a solution?

```
echo "<form action=\"\" method =\"get\">";
echo "<input id=\"input\" type=\"text\" name=\"page\" placeholder=\"Input your data..\">";
echo "</form>";
```

This is what i've got so far

Comment: _“I know how to achieve this with _GET or _POST but using them is not an option”_ – _why_ not? _“Can some one please offer a solution?”_ – read the input field value with JavaScript, and then just “redirect” to the desired target URL by assigning the appropriate value to `window.location.href`.

Comment: Why is neither GET nor POST an option? These are the ways to transfer user input to the server...

Comment: apparently the goal isn't to transfer input to the server, it's to redirect to a certain location.

Comment: I do have a get. So let's say when user enters data '123'. He gets redirected to page site.com/?page=123 and server collects 123. But i want him to go to site.com/123/ and then mod_rewrite would do the work to understand what that /123/ means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you decide to do it client or server side, in the end it is always going to be GET or POST somewhere. How would you have it delivered it another way ? ;)
As hinted by the others, do you mean you don't want to contact the server on submit ?
Can you be more precise ?

Ok, then in this case you need to do two things:
in your .htaccess or virtualhost 
`RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?page=$1`, assuming mod_rewrite is enabled the page that handles the submissionis called index.php.
Then you need to change your redirect to point to the site.com/123 page and it should work.

Comment: I do have a get. So let's say when user enters data '123'. He gets redirected to page site.com/?page=123 and server collects 123. But i want him to go to site.com/123/ and then mod_rewrite would do the work to understand what that /123/ means

Comment: Ok, then in this case you need to do two things:

Answer (score 1):

Without much more info, I would suggest an event handler that listens for the enter key, then a simple javascript redirect using the value from your input box 
:

```
window.onkeypress = function(k){ 
  if(k.keyCode == 13)  {
      url = window.location.host + "/" + document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value + "/";
      window.location = url;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the FORM "action" attribute:

```
<form action="http://www.google.com">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit!" />
</form>
```

Note: This will not work in JSFiddle due to X-FRAME-OPTIONS. You have likely tried this solution, but I offer it because you specify that you cannot declare "method". Like CBroe, I'd like to know why. Your data will be based along via the default method, which is GET.